# $\mathbb{A}^1$ action on cones

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I often see it said that given a scheme $X$ and a graded sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$-algebras $\mathcal{S}$ the *cone* Spec $S$ has a natural $\mathbb{A}^1$-action on it induced from the grading on $S$.

But the grading on $\mathcal{S}$ is discrete ($\mathbb{Z}$-graded), whereas the action of $\mathbb{A}^1$ is continuous. What is this natural morphism $\mathbb{A}^1 \times \text{Spec } S \to \text{Spec } S$? I cannot see it.

Comment: I assume you meant that $\mathcal{S}$ is a sheaf of graded $\mathcal{O}_X$-algebras? Moreover, I think that it should be an action of the multiplicative group $\mathbb{A}^1_S \setminus \{0\}=\mathbb{G}_{m,S}$. The construction can be found in glorious detail [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/affine+line#Grading).

Comment: @user45878 Yes I meant a sheaf of graded $\mathcal{O}_X$ algebras (edited to fix this). But I did mean $\mathbb{A}^1$ not $\mathbb{G}_m$. I was reading this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9601010

Comment: Yeah it comes down to the same thing, multiplication by $0$ should just send everything to the origin (she writes multiplicative notation)

Comment: The action is by multiplication: elements of degree $n$ are multiplied by $t^n$ where $t \in \mathbb{A}^1$. For this to be an action by possibly non-invertible scalars the grading needs to be nonnegative.

Comment: But if I have a point in an arbitrary cone $p \in \text{Spec } S$ and $t \in \mathbb{A}^1$, what is the definition of $t^n \cdot p$? I tried looking at this affine-locally and its not clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking locally on $X$, we can assume $X=\operatorname{Spec} A$ and we can consider $\mathcal{S}$ as simply a graded $A$-algebra $B=\bigoplus_{n\in\mathbb{N}} B_n$, and $\operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{S}$ is just $\operatorname{Spec} B$.  To give a map $\mathbb{A}^1\times \operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{S}\to \operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{S}$ then, we just have to give an $A$-algebra homomorphism $\varphi:B\to B[t]$.  This homomorphism is simply the homomorphism that sends each $b\in B_n$ to $t^nb$.

For a simple example, take $A$ to be a field and $B=A[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ to be a polynomial ring with its usual grading.  Then $\operatorname{Spec} B$ is just $\mathbb{A}^n$, and our action $\mathbb{A}^1\times\mathbb{A}^n\to \mathbb{A}^n$ is dual to the homomorphism $A[x_1,\dots,x_n]\to A[x_1,\dots,x_n,t]$ which sends $x_i$ to $tx_i$ for each $i$ (since each $x_i$ has degree $1$).  Geometrically, this means the action sends $(t,x_1,\dots,x_n)\to (tx_1,\dots,tx_n)$.  That is, it is just the usual action of $\mathbb{A}^1$ on $\mathbb{A}^n$ by scalar multiplication.

(Note that it is necessary for $\mathcal{S}$ to be $\mathbb{N}$-graded rather than $\mathbb{Z}$-graded here.  If it is only $\mathbb{Z}$-graded, our homomorphism $\varphi$ would land in $B[t,t^{-1}]$ instead and we would get just a map  $(\mathbb{A}^1\setminus\{0\})\times \operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{S}\to \operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{S}$, which is an action of $\mathbb{G}_m$ rather than $\mathbb{A}^1$.)

Comment: Thanks! Coincidentally, this helped me understand another question I had which was why an action of $\mathbb{G}_m$ on Spec$(R)$ induces a $\mathbb{Z}$-grading on $R$.